# preg_match is not working good in my condition

Tags: php, regex

This is my code to get content between html tags.

```
$stringtext=file_get_contents($url);

$frm1=htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['from1']);
$to1=htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['to1']);

$dt= find_between($newstr,$frm1,$to1);

function find_between($string, $start, $end, $trim = true, $greedy = false)        {

$pattern = '/'.preg_quote($start,'\"').'(.*';
if (!$greedy) $pattern .= '?';
 $pattern .= ')'.preg_quote($end,'/').'/s';

preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
$string = $matches[0];
if ($trim) {
    $string = substr($string, strlen($start));
    $string = substr($string, 0,-strlen($end));
}

return $string;
}
```

It return null.

if I write pattern like this

```
$pattern = '/<td valign\="top">(.*?)<\/td>/s';
```

It works fine.

This is html form to enter value of frm1 and to1.

```
<form action="" method="post" id="frm1" style="display:none">


<table>
    <tr>
        <td>From: <input type="text" name="from1" /></td>
        <td>To: <input type="text" name="to1" /></td>
    </tr>
</table></form>
```

Comment: Use DOMDocument, not a direct string approach.

Comment: @casimire I am fresher. Please explain how to use DOMDucument

Comment: You must find a tutorial for that since it isn't in the scope of SO and is too long to explain. To make it short, DOMDocument build a tree with an XML or html document. Then you can more easily (without errors) query it or edit it.

Comment: Let it print ``$pattern`` to debug your code. This might help.

Answer (score 0):

As Casimimir has already pointed out, use a Parser (e.g. `SimpleXML`) instead.
Consider the following code with two alternatives:

```
<?php
$html = '
<form action="" method="post" id="frm1" style="display:none">

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>From: <input type="text" name="from1" /></td>
        <td>To: <input type="text" name="to1" /></td>
    </tr>
</table></form>
';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($html);

# traverse the DOM directly
$input_version1 = $xml->table->tr->td->input;

# use an xpath query to get the same element
$input_version2 = $xml->xpath("//form//input[@name='from1']")[0];

print_r($input_version1);
print_r($input_version2);
?>
```

A good introduction to `SimpleXML` can be found [here](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-To-SimpleXML-With-PHP.html).

Comment: SimpleXML is designed for XML not for html. For example it will fail on all unclosed tags, like `<br>`, `<input>` ... if the `/>` (to self close the tag) is missing, or when there's no root element. If the source code has the slightest error from xml syntax, `simplexml_load...` will fail and since html is very permissive... (as an aside simplexml isn't simple at all).

Answer (score 0):

```
function find_between($string, $start, $end, $trim = true, $greedy = false)        {
$start=htmlspecialchars_decode($start);
$end=htmlspecialchars_decode($end);

$pattern = '/'.preg_quote($start,'\"').'(.*';
if (!$greedy) $pattern .= '?';
 $pattern .= ')'.preg_quote($end,'/').'/s';

preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
$string = $matches[0];
if ($trim) {
$string = substr($string, strlen($start));
$string = substr($string, 0,-strlen($end));
}

return $string;
}
```